# object-fit + position fixed + vh border bug in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fixed

Playing with css object-fit I'm getting some strange behavior in Chrome (44.0.2403.89 and also canary) object-fit stop working in this layout (combination between object-fit positioned fixed and the parent with vh units) if I add a border in the image the problem seems to get solved, another way to fix this is to don't have any others elements in the layout (not really a fix).

Sorry is really hard to explain with words, so better check this pen in chrome, comment the css border line and you will get the bug.
comment `border: 1px solid black;`

http://codepen.io/octavioamu/pen/bdmEob

There is some information about this? Is really a bug or I am missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like it was solved.